# Cube root of unity: what is $w$ given $(1+w)(1+w^2)(1+w^3)\dots(1+w^{3n})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

If $w$ is the cube root of unity, then what is the value of the following expression?
$$(1+w)(1+w^2)(1+w^3)\dots(1+w^{3n})$$
My try: I have tried ways to solve it by using $1+w+w^2=0$ but failed. Is there any other method? Please inform.

All I know is that $1+w+w^2=0$. Please let me know if this can be of any help. Also, please suggest me ways to simplify this.

Comment: Have you tried working this out manually for $n = 1, 2$? A pattern may emerge. (Also, the roots of $1 + w + w^2$ are the /primitive/ cube roots of unity.)

Comment: What is $w^3$? how about $w^{3n}$ and how about $w^{5}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $w^3=1$ by definition, so the expression reduces to
$$(1+w)(1+w^2)(1+1)(1+w)(1+w^2)(1+1)\dots(1+1)$$
$$=(2(1+w)(1+w^2))^n$$
$$=(2(1+w+w^2+1))^n$$
$$=(2(0+1))^n=2^n$$

Comment: Perfectly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

From the definition of $w$,
$$1+w^{3k}=1+1,\\1+w^{3k+1}=1+w,\\1+w^{3k+2}=1+w^2,$$

and

$$(1+w)(1+w^2)=1+w+w^2+w^3=1.$$

edit: equation had a tiny mistake

Comment: Thanks. Though I knew it, would be useful for others reading the post, so deserves an upvote

Comment: "Though I knew it": why did you ask, then ??

Comment: Sorry but could not apply it at that moment. Appreciate your effort though.

Comment: that equality (Last one) does not seem tright